# How to get objectId for the current Azure DevOps pipeline service principle?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

In my release pipeline, I'm running an Azure Cli task with a PowerShell script. In the script, I want to grant the current pipeline SP a list secret permission for one azure Key vault.

For doing this, I will need the ObjectId for the current pipeline SP. Turns out this is the hardest thing ever. The pipeline settings only allow return PrincipaleId, then I tried `az ad sp show --id $env:servicePrincipalId --query objectId -o tsv`.  However, this always returns empty string, I guess since the pipeline is authed by a token, Azure does not allow it to get info about itself.

Wondering how can I get this magic ObjectId for the current pipeline other than just pass the value in from pipeline variable

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this maybe a bug for Azure Cli version 2.4X.X, I reported it to MS: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with "**objectId**" parameter value. I have tried to replicate the same in Azure Portal. Instead of using **objectId** use **id** parameter, it will work.

```
az ad sp show *********** --query id -o tsv
```

[image]

Replicated the same in portal.

1. Created a new Service principal

[image]

here are the service principal details:
[image]

Step2:
run the command with **objectId** parameter, output is empty.  When we update with "id" it working as expected.
[image]

Comment: MS should really fix this, the property name is "objectId" and you can really query it out by using "id".....

Comment: Ah, it might a bug with certain the Azure CLI version. objectId works in version 2.34.1 but not in version 2.42.0